# Need to link directory information to another list

Tags: list, form

I have two different lists that I am working with:

- Directory
- Employee Out

The Directory has all the up-to-date information pertaining to each employee as far as name, team, email, and phone number.  The employee out list is just as it sounds, just documenting when an employee is out.

I would the like the employee out list form to have some automation in some capacity.  When I go to type in the name of an employee in the employee out list, I would like the team field to be populated by grabbing that information from the directory.

What are my options with this?

Answer (score 0):

Either Rest/JSON or JavaScript Client Object model will work perfectly in your case. you can probably make a Rest call with JQuery onchange method, pass the employee name or ID to the rest call, you would get  Json object from which you can read the team information and use jquery to apply these values on your NewForm.aspx on Employee Out. 
And for JavaScript Client Object Model, SP.ClientContext, and do an context.executeQueryAsync, you would get the results in onQuerySucceeded, which you could apply in your page using JQuery/JavaScript.

You could look up samples of the code on internet for reference. Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please provide a link to what you referenced?

Comment: What I suggested is a general approach and you can do your research in those terms, I did not refer any particular article in any website.